# Android : custom action bar layout cut issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I have problem with custom action bar, layout goes outside of the window or half appear , I have used four `Relativelayout` inside `Linearlayout` , just i want to make it something like tabbar. but the problem is that when i am using this layout, actionbar not fully appeared,   i have posted xml and code below, i have also tried to show it in picture

**actionbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/themecolor"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/papertext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Paper"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/papertab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/paperv"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/paperv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/papertext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Explorer"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/newstracktab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/newstrackv"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/newstrackv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.40"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/papertext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Explorer"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/Explorertab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/Explorerv"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/Explorerv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/section"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupActionBar();
    }

    public void setupActionBar() {
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
    }
}
```

**I got Something like this**

[image]

**I want something like this**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.30"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/papertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Paper"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/papertab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/paperv"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/paperv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/papertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Explorer"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/newstracktab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/newstrackv"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/newstrackv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.35"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/papertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Explorer"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/Explorertab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Explorerv"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/Explorerv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/section"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```